Freyd's theorem fails for categories that are not locally small
The main ingredient in Freyd's adjoint functor theorem and related results is the following observation:

Freyd's criterion for initial objects. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a locally small category which has all small limits. Assume that $\mathcal{C}$ has a weakly initial set of objects: this means that every object of $\mathcal{C}$ admits a (possible non-unique) morphism from one object in $S$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ has an initial object.

The assumption of having a weakly initial set is necessary: Consider the partially ordered collection of ordinal numbers $(\mathbf{On},\leq)$, regarded as a thin category. It has all small colimits, but no terminal object. Now take the dual.
Question. What is an example showing that also the assumption that $\mathcal{C}$ is locally small is necessary in Freyd's criterion? That is, what is an example of a (non locally small) category with small limits and a weakly initial set, which however doesn't have an initial object?
The proof uses this assumption in a crucial way. Let me sketch it. Let $P$ be product of all objects in the weakly initial set. Then $P$ is a weakly initial object. Define $E$ as the multiple equalizer of all morphisms $P \to P$. Then one checks that $E$ has no subobject except for $E$. Using equalizers, this implies that morphisms out of $E$ are unique, so it's initial.
This proof shows that we don't really need that the whole category is locally small. We only need that the collection $\mathrm{End}(P)$ is a set. It would also be sufficient to require that the collection $\mathrm{Sub}(P)$ is a set.
I have tried to construct an example where $\mathrm{End}(P)$ is merely a collection (with monoid structure), but it is not so easy to guarantee that the category still has all small limits. In particular, one-object categories will not work.
I know that Freyd's criterion is applied in practice only to categories which are locally small anyway. But I want to make really sure that this assumption is necessary for the theorem to hold.
Notice that if $\mathcal{C}$ is a counterexample for the criterion above, then the unique functor $\mathcal{C} \to 1$ is a counterexample for Freyd's adjoint functor theorem for non-locally small categories.

It's obviously not necessary. Take any non-locally small category with an initial object. Then that initial object comprises the required weakly initial set.

Your comment doesn't answer my question. I am looking for a category with small limits which has a weakly initial set but not an initial object.

Then ask that question. The question as written is different.

From the votes I assume it's only you who misunderstood the question. I ask for a counterexample of Freyd's criterion when we drop the locally small assumption. What you then get is precisely the question in my previous comment. You have simply read a different question which I never asked. Thanks for the downvote anyway.

I didn't downvote. Your question: "What is an example showing that also the assumption that is locally small is necessary in Freyd's criterion?" I give: an example satisfying the conclusion but not the premise. That is precisely a demonstration that the assumption is not necessary.

This is an interesting misunderstanding; I think the cause is an overloading of the word "necessary". When a theorem says $\forall x. P(x) \to Q(x)$, to say that $P$ is necessary means that $\forall x. Q(x)$ does not hold. This is different from the usual meaning of "necessary", where $P$ being necessary for $Q$ would mean that $\forall x. Q(x) \to P(x)$. Martin meant the first one but Zhen understood the second one. (In this case $P$ is "locally small" and $Q$ is "small limits + weakly initial set → initial object".)

I think the first usage is an abuse of terminology. We can certainly talk about hypotheses being necessary for a proof and mean something like that but it is unjustifiable to extend this to propositions.

I didn’t check all the details, but I’m pretty sure this is correct. For simplicity, fix an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ and interpret “small” to mean having cardinality smaller than $\kappa$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$ whose objects are all sets of cardinality smaller than or equal to $\kappa$ and whose morphisms are maps $f: A \to B$ where $|f^{-1}(b)| < \kappa$ for all $b \in B$. Than $\mathcal{D}$ has small coproducts and coequalizers, the same as in $\mathbf{Set}$, so it has all small colimits. It has a weakly terminal object, namely, any set whose cardinality is $\kappa$, but it has no terminal object. Now, just take $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{D}^{\text{op}}$.

I just realized it is a bit strange to define “small” as having cardinality below $\kappa$. Small sets in that case would model $\mathbf{ZFC}$ with atoms as opposed to the usual $\mathbf{ZFC}$. Instead, I should have defined “small” as meaning belonging to $V_\kappa$ and taken $\mathcal{D}$ to have as objects all sets in $V_{\kappa + 1}$. The example otherwise works exactly the same.

Are you sure that this category has all small coproducts?

@MartinBrandenburg The same coproduct as in $\mathbf{Set}$ works, no? The index set being small ensures the condition on cardinalities of inverse images still holds.

Why should the disjoint union satisfy the cardinality assumption?

@MartinBrandenburg The disjoint union of smaller than $\kappa$ many sets, each of cardinality at most $\kappa$, has cardinality at most $\kappa$. (“Small” is being interpreted as having cardinality smaller than $\kappa$.)

The disjoint union does not satisfy the universal property. (Take $\kappa$ many copies of $1$ and try to map it to $1$.)

@ZhenLin Only “small” coproducts are assumed to exist. There’s no reason why the coproduct of $\kappa$ many copies of $1$ needs to exist. (Again, “small” means cardinality being smaller than $\kappa$.)

Ah, right. There should be a way to construct this category in terms of the indexed category of large families of small sets but I'm not seeing it...

I am still not sure about the precise definitions here. Let $U$ be a Grothendieck universe. We consider categories based on sets only,  and define small := element of $U$. Now I assume you want to define the category whose objects are the subsets of $U$? Or do you actually want those sets that are isomorphic to a subset of $U$? (This seems to be important to build the coequalizers?) Regarding the morphisms, do we take maps such that every fiber is an element of $U$ Or do we only require that they are isomorphic to elements of $U$?

@MartinBrandenburg I believe this can work either way, but for concreteness, let’s just say small means elements of $U$, the category has objects all subsets of $U$. This does not really affect whether coequalizers exist or not - the usual coequalizer in $\mathbf{Set}$ may be only isomorphic to a subset of $U$, but coequalizers are only defined up to isomorphisms anyway. For morphisms, since we’re taking objects as subsets of $U$, fibers, assumed to have cardinalities smaller than $|U|$, are automatically elements of $U$.

@MartinBrandenburg (Or you could do it the other way around and let the category have as objects all sets of cardinality at most $|U|$ and fibers of morphisms are only assumed to have cardinalities below $|U|$. It really doesn’t matter.)

Alright. I checked the details now. Thanks a lot! This is a really weird category but I didn't expect anything else here. :D A more low-level analogue would be the category of countable sets where morphisms are maps with finite fibers. It has a weakly terminal object, countable colimits, but doesn't have a terminal object. (I have never seen this category either before.)

@MartinBrandenburg You're welcome. Though the countable example won't work, as it only has finite coproducts - for example, the disjoint union of countably infinite many $1$, while countable, will fail the universal property for coproducts, since it cannot map to $1$ with finite fibers. Coequalizers won't work in general either. The smallest example you can get is the category of sets of cardinalities at most $\aleph_1$ where morphisms are maps with countable fibers. Then you do have countable colimits, weakly terminal objects, but no terminal object. (In general, one can replace $\aleph_1$...

@MartinBrandenburg ... by any uncountable regular cardinal $\kappa$. Then the category of sets of cardinalities $\leq \kappa$ and morphisms maps with fibers of cardinalities $<\kappa$ has all colimits where the diagram has cardinality $<\kappa$, weakly terminal objects, but no terminal object.)

@MartinBrandenburg I've never seen this category before myself either. It's more just that I saw your question, and originally thought about playing around with a category consisting of either $\leq\kappa$ products or coproducts of some structures of cardinalities $\leq\kappa$, before suddenly noticing that controlling the sizes of fibers makes both coproducts and coequalizers work. It's quite weird to me as well.

Thanks a lot for the clarification.
